# Connecting Event Grid subscription to seperate Event Grid topic

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I'm trying to create an event grid subscription that will send messages directly from the originating event grid topic to a separate event grid topic in a different subscription.

I'm able to successfully create a web hook based subscription (through the Azure portal) but when a message gets send it fails with the reason "Unauthorized".

I then added the aeg-sas-key to the header of the subscription with the key value of the receiving topic and this resulted in failures with "BadRequest" errors.

Is it possible to directly connect event grid topics through a subscription or do I need to put some logic in between to handle this flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribed a custom event grid topic (via a webhook endpoint) to the **CloudEventSchemaV1_0** subscription.

Note, that the custom event grid topic will validate a webhook endpoint only for that schema using the Http *OPTIONS* method, where the *WebHook-Allowed-Origin* header is returned with a singular asterisk character ('*'), indicating that the delivery target supports notifications from all origins.

The following screen snippet shows an AEG cascading:

[image]